# Serve static files for a nodeJs application in Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Which the different steps to do make serving static images possible in case of a nodeJs app without the need of using S3

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I tried some solutions but still doesn't work

NB: I'm new in AWS, thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions as per the documentation below:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

You don't need any additional changes in Elastic Beanstalk to serve static files.